# Preseed doesn't automatically select network interface on Ubuntu 14.04; automated install needs human input

Tags: pxe, preseed

I'm trying to setup an unattended Ubuntu Server 14.04 installation from PXE.

I initially tried using Kickstart. This worked okay except that the partition manager required user confirmation and so wasn't a fully unattended install (i.e. I'd need to acknowledge that it's okay to repartition the disk part way through the installation).

A colleague suggested that, for fine-grained control, I'd be better off using Preseed. Unfortunately, the preseed installation currently gets stuck at the `choose_interface` section.

The boot instructions in `/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default`:

```
KERNEL images/ubuntu_server_1404/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
append auto=true vga=normal initrd=images/ubuntu_server_1404/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz url=http://myNAS/pxe/preseed.cfg quiet --
```

are able to execute the first few lines (e.g. language/keyboard selection)

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us
```

but the `choose_interface` doesn't work automatically:

[image]

I've tried both specifying the network interface:

```
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select em1
```

and automatic selection:

```
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
```

Neither of these settings worked: the installation requires human input in order to proceed.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is (or was?) a reported [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netcfg/+bug/855921). The solution was to try passing `netcfg/choose_interface= YourInterface` to the kernel as a [boot option](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/i386/apbs02.html.en).

Comment: @Ron Could you explain HOW to "pass `netcfg/choose_interface= YourInterface` to the kernel as a boot option." by editing your answer?

Comment: add ```netcfg/choose_interface=``` at the end of the ```append``` line in the pxe config that you show above (before ```--```)

Comment: Seems that bug report was closed because you can't set the interfacd options if you're loading your preseed file config over the network.

Comment: You can chainload multiple preseed files, so you could include a minimal preseed with just enough to get started and then use the preseed option to load another preseed from the network which will run when the network is available and merge and override the options from the first preseed.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2017/automating-preseed-interface-selection-ubuntu/), you can edit pxelinux.cfg in `append` line for multiple interface issue when using preseed.

by interface name

```
append initrd=/images/Ubuntu/initrd.gz ksdevice=bootif lang= interface=eth1
```

or with mac address

```
append initrd=/images/Ubuntu/initrd.gz ksdevice=bootif lang= interface=90:e2:ba:2e:b0:70
```